# Removing whitespace while typing into text field

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have just added a text field that allows users to input recipients email addresses before within the app rather than within the email view.

I want to restrict users from entering spaces so that they can't input invalid email addresses.

This is the code I came up with but it doesn't do anything when run:

```
func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
    var text = emailText.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
    emailText.text = text
}
```

How can I replace any instances of whitespace while the user is typing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add that method as a target for events of the text field.  In your `viewDidLoad`, add this line:

```
yourTextField.addTarget(self, 
    action: "textFieldDidChange", 
    forControlEvents: .EditingChanged
)
```

---

Alternatively, and perhaps better, you could set your view controller to be the text field's delegate:

```
yourTextField.delegate = self
```

And then implement the following text field delegate method:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField!, shouldChangeCharactersInRange 
    range: NSRange, replacementString string: String!) -> Bool
```

If the replacement string contains white space, return `false`.

Also, consider there are white space characters other than just a simple space.  You probably want to check the replacement string against `NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()`